# Getting Null pointer exception during String comparison

Tags: java, android, string, class, nullpointerexception

I getting `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference` when passing class reference to a method.
The line causing the error is:

```
if (!contactData.getContactNo().equals("")){
```

**More of code:**

Invocation of method:

```
recContDBHelper.insertRecord(new ContactData("", number, date)); <--Exception here
```

Invoked method:

```
 public void insertRecord(ContactData contactData) {
        String name = "";
        if (!contactData.getContactNo().equals("")) { <--exception here
            name = CommonServices.getContactDisplayNameByNumber(contactData.getContactNo(), context);
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                name = contactData.getContactNo();
            }
        }
    }
```

In the above code `contactData.getContactNo()` return type is `String`.

Exception is:

```
04-12 18:21:40.153: E/AndroidRuntime(27924): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-12 18:21:40.153: E/AndroidRuntime(27924): Process: com.stackoverflow.ranjith.androidprojdel, PID: 27924
04-12 18:21:40.153: E/AndroidRuntime(27924): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.stackoverflow.ranjith.androidprojdel.PhoneCallreceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
04-12 18:21:40.153: E/AndroidRuntime(27924):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2586)
04-12 18:21:40.153: E/AndroidRuntime(27924):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:144)
04-12 18:21:40.153: E/AndroidRuntime(27924):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
04-12 18:21:40.153: E/AndroidRuntime(27924):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-12 18:21:40.153: E/AndroidRuntime(27924):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-12 18:21:40.153: E/AndroidRuntime(27924):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
04-12 18:21:40.153: E/AndroidRuntime(27924):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-12 18:21:40.153: E/AndroidRuntime(27924):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-12 18:21:40.153: E/AndroidRuntime(27924):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
04-12 18:21:40.153: E/AndroidRuntime(27924):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
04-12 18:21:40.153: E/AndroidRuntime(27924): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
04-12 18:21:40.153: E/AndroidRuntime(27924):    at com.stackoverflow.ranjith.androidprojdel.recentlyContacted.RecContDBHelper.insertRecord(RecContDBHelper.java:57)
04-12 18:21:40.153: E/AndroidRuntime(27924):    at com.stackoverflow.ranjith.androidprojdel.PhoneCallreceiver.onReceive(PhoneCallreceiver.java:93)
04-12 18:21:40.153: E/AndroidRuntime(27924):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2579)
04-12 18:21:40.153: E/AndroidRuntime(27924):    ... 9 more
```

The `ContactData` class:

```
public class ContactData {
    private String contact_name;
    private String ph_no;
    private String time_call;

    public ContactData(String contact_name, String ph_no, String time_call) {
        this.contact_name = contact_name;
        this.ph_no = ph_no;
        this.time_call = time_call;
    }

    public ContactData(String contact_name, String ph_no) {
        this.contact_name = contact_name;
        this.ph_no = ph_no;
    }

    public String getContactNo() {
        return this.ph_no;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
if (contactData.getContactNo() != null && !contactDate.getContactNo().isEmpty()) {
    // your code here
}
```

It seems that `contactData.getContactNo()` is returning `null`.

Comment: How can it be null.. I am passing `new ContactData("", number, date)` to the method.

Comment: Yes ... but what does the call return?  Is it returning the value of a variable that hasn't been initialized?  What does the code say?

Comment: at least two possibilities: 1. number is null when create the object. 2 your getter returns null

Comment: @Ranjith you are getting null from your getter. You should elaborate more on `ContactData` class

Comment: @Froyo Added the ContactData class

Comment: @Ranjith and make sure that `number` variable is not null in your constructor call.

Comment: You are right. The value of number is null due to some reason. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to invoke methods on instance without making sure that it is not null.
In your case contactData.getContactNo is null and when you are trying to invoke equals method on it NPE is thrown.
There are two ways of avoiding it. First one is to compare the empty string with contactData.getContactNo else make sure that contactData and contact.getContactNo is not null.

Eg:

```
"".equals(contactData.getContactNo)
```

or

```
if(contactData != null && contactData.getContactNo != null)
```